# Variable as multiple command parameters ignore quotes in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, parameters

I want to insert a variable (basically a read text file) into a command body as multiple parameters, but this doesn't work because the variable is not resolved properly.

My variable

```
MAIN_MENU="1 'Create new image' 2 'Start image as overriding' 3 'Start image as snapshot' 4 'Install OS' 5 'Settings'"
```

Echoes:

```
echo $MAIN_MENU
1 'Create_new_image' 2 'Start_image _as_overriding' 3 'Start _image_as_snapshot' 4 'Install_OS' 5 'Settings'
```

Which is what I expect and if I copy paste the echo result (by hand) to command parameters like below, it works.

```
dialog --title "Title" --menu 'Choose operation:' 0 0 5 1 'Create new image' 2 'Start image as overriding' 3 'Start image as snapshot' 4 'Install OS' 5 'Settings'
```

In this case, parameters are
...
**1; Create new image; 2; Start image as overriding**
...

However, when I insert the parameters as a variable, it ignores the single quotes completely..

```
MAIN_MENU="1 'Create new image' 2 'Start image as overriding' 3 'Start image as snapshot' 4 'Install OS' 5 'Settings'"
dialog --title "Title" --menu 'Choose operation:' 0 0 5 $MAIN_MENU
```

Basically leaving single quotes there, but also separating the parameters by spaces..

In this case, parameters are
...
**1; 'Create; new; image'; 2; 'Start; image; as; overriding';**
...

No amount of quote swapping resulted in coveted results for me.

Comment: Use array, not var `MAIN_MENU=( 1 'Create new image' 2 'Start image as overriding' 3 'Start image as snapshot' 4 'Install OS' 5 'Settings' );
echo "${MAIN_MENU[@]}"`

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked!

Comment: @kvantour No, because that creates *single* argument to `dialog`, which is expecting multiple pairs of arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After parameter expansion, any quotes in the result are treated as literal characters, not syntax for escaping whitespace. The correct way to create a list of values is to use an array, which acts as a second layer of quoting to allow whitespace in each element. As a bonus, array assignments also allow for more readable formatting.

```
MAIN_MENU=(
  1 'Create new image'   # Comments can be added, as well
  2 'Start image as overriding'
  3 'Start image as snapshot'
  4 'Install OS'
  5 'Settings'
)
dialog --title "Title" --menu 'Choose operation:' 0 0 5 "${MAIN_MENU[@]}"
```